# Dapper me añade \r\n al final de algunos strings al mapear el resultado de una consulta

Tags: c#, .net, dapper

al mapear el resultado de una consulta a un objeto, en algunos campos de tipo string,
no en todos (lo que me resulta aún mas raro) me añade \r\n en la propiedad del objeto.
Para descartar que me venga de la base de datos, les hago un TRIM a todos los Varchar, pero aun y así en algunas me continua añadiendo el retorno de carro, alguien me puede decir el porque ?
Esta es la consulta:

```
SELECT 
RTRIM(LTRIM(DEVICE.MB_CustomerCity)) AS city, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(DEVICE.MB_Model)) AS model, 
RTRIM(LTRIM(DEVICE.MB_Service)) AS line_profile,
DEVICE.MB_VoIP AS voip_profile
FROM MB_Clientes as CUSTOMER LEFT OUTER JOIN
MB_clientKrill as DEVICE ON  CUSTOMER.CodigoCliente = DEVICE.CodigoCliente Where RTRIM(LTRIM(customer.CodigoCliente))='000001'
```

El modelo:

```
public class device
{
 
    [Required]
    public string model { get; set; }
    public string city { get; set; } = "";
    public string line_profile { get; set; }
    public object voip_profile { get; set; }
   
}
```

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

en vez de trim(), yo te comendaría usar string.Replace("\r\n", "") y deberías tener el problema resuelto, en caso contrario string.Replace(@"\r\n", "").